# Calender module not working with cck date field

Tags: views, 6, entities, datetime

I have installed calendar module and create a view with display style calender. I want to display the contents in calender on the basis of a cck date field.

I have created a view and added cck field as argument and add the same field in field section. But in calender display there is no content is displaying.

If I add node post date field instead of cck field then calender is working properly. Is there any special settings required for cck field work with calender module? Any help appreciated.

This is my views settings:
[image]

Argument Settings:
[image]

Comment: I use CCK date fields with D6 all the time, so, this *should* work. But, as you know, calendar is quite particular, so, make sure the formatting of the date is correct.  A quick look at a calendar here shows I have the granularity of the date argument set to Month for a monthly calendar, and the readme.txt also mentions `The argument value will be YYYY-MM-DD for a day, YYYY-MM for a month, YYYY for a year, and YYYY-W99 for a week,` so perhaps it's something simple like that?

Comment: you mean i need to change the date format for field in content type field settings? i have updated the question, added argument field settings image also.

Comment: no, I mean in the ARGUMENTS area.  There you need to set the granularity to MONTH so the Calendar knows what month to filter on.  It's set right below "Action to take if argument is not present," etc.

Comment: But yes, after seeing the new screenshot, those are set correctly.

Comment: I need to add any other field in field section?

Comment: another thing that might be happening is if you have a lot of `page` and `story` nodes and all of them don't have this cck date field, and thus with your paging only 10, you aren't getting to this one. (obviously all nodes have the node post date field :)

Comment: i am trying calender module in my fresh drupal installation. I have created only two nodes of type page.

Comment: well that's not it then lol.  what is the exact format of that cck date field?  eg, date stamp, date time, etc?

Comment: field type is Date
widget tye is Text field with Date popup calendar